# Getting id of last inserted row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have been trying to get the last inserted id into my code but i get 11 or 12 as the returned id, if the parameter type is set to either int 32 or int64 respectively.

**This is the procedure i am using**

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Sophia_FND_SalesOrder_CREATE](
@contact int,
@deliveryAddress varchar(50), 
@Charge float, 
@GrossTotal float, 
@PaymentMode varchar(50), 
@organisationId int, 
@userid varchar(50),
@amtpaid float,
@SalesOrderId int OUTPUT
)
as
begin
insert into Sophia_FND_SalesOrder(ContactId, deliveryAddress, Charge, GrossTotal, PaymentMode, organisationId,userid, AmountPaid)
values(@contact,@deliveryAddress, @Charge, @GrossTotal, @PaymentMode, @organisationId, @userid, @amtpaid)
SET @SalesOrderId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN  @SalesOrderId
end
```

**This is the function i am using in my class**

```
 Public Shared Function Create_salesOrder(ByVal contact As Integer, ByVal deliveryAddress As String, ByVal Charge As Double, ByVal GrossTotal As Double, ByVal PaymentMode As String, ByVal organisationId As Integer, ByVal userid As String, ByVal amtpaid As Double) As Integer

        Dim comm As DbCommand = CreateCommand17()
        comm.CommandText = "Sophia_FND_SalesOrder_CREATE"

        AddParameter(comm, "@contact", contact, DbType.Int64)
        AddParameter(comm, "@deliveryAddress", deliveryAddress, DbType.String)
        AddParameter(comm, "@Charge", Charge, DbType.Double)
        AddParameter(comm, "@GrossTotal", GrossTotal, DbType.Double)
        AddParameter(comm, "@PaymentMode", PaymentMode, DbType.String)
        AddParameter(comm, "@organisationId", organisationId, DbType.Int64)
        AddParameter(comm, "@userid", userid, DbType.String)
        AddParameter(comm, "@amtpaid", amtpaid, DbType.Double)
        AddParameter(comm, "@SalesOrderId", DbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)




        Dim id As Integer
        Dim insertResult As Int32 = -1
        Try

            insertResult = ExecuteNonQuery6(comm)
            id = Convert.ToInt64(comm.Parameters("@SalesOrderId").Value)
        Catch ex As Exception

            Throw ex
        End Try
        'Return insertResult <> -1
        Return id
    End Function
```

**This is how i call it in my code behind**

```
 Dim sale_id As Integer
            If IsNothing(Session("soid")) Then
                sale_id = Create_salesOrder(CInt(drpcontact.SelectedValue), txtdelivery.Text, lblCharge_unformated.Text, total, drpPayMode.SelectedItem.Text, SessionWrapper.OrganisationId, SessionWrapper.LoggedInUserID, CDbl(txtpayment.Text))
                If Not IsNothing(sale_id) Then
                    Session("soid") = sale_id

                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessagePanel.CssClass = "errorMessage"
                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessagePanel.Visible = True
                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessageLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessageLabel.Text = "done"
                     FillGridview()
                Else
                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessagePanel.CssClass = "errorMessage"
                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessagePanel.Visible = True
                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessageLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                    Me.MessageBoard1.MessageLabel.Text = "Error Occured on creating sales"
                End If
end if
```

> I found a way that work but the syntax is entirely different and i would like to stick to my syntax. The problem should be in my class function but i cant seem to know where i did the mistake.

*Whenever i run this, i either get 11 or 12 as the return id which is totally wrong*

**Thanks**

Comment: I don't see any issue with this code. Can you explain what's the issue with this code in detail.

Comment: i test in the sql studio, all works well, but when i test the function,
 i either get 11 or 12. </br>the returned id is always 11 if the parameter type( `AddParameter(comm, "@SalesOrderId", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output)`
) is set to int32 and it is 12 if the parameter type( `AddParameter(comm, "@SalesOrderId", DbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)`
) is int64  @praveen

Comment: Hello Nipek ,Use ExecuteScaler instead of ExecuteNonQuery and try, Hope It works.

Comment: i got 0 as the id @MohanSingh . thanks for the try though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change put this in my code behind and this seems to work for me. Thanks

```
 Dim sale_id As Integer
            '  Dim saleslastid As Integer
            Dim salecreate_line As Boolean
            If IsNothing(Session("soid")) Then
                '  slastid = SalesOrder_id()
                '  saleslastid = StringHelper_2_0.ClearDBNullError(slastid.Rows(0)("id"))
                'sale_id = Create_salesOrder(CInt(drpcontact.SelectedValue), txtdelivery.Text, lblCharge_unformated.Text, total, drpPayMode.SelectedItem.Text, SessionWrapper.OrganisationId, SessionWrapper.LoggedInUserID, CDbl(txtpayment.Text))
                Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SophiaERP_Foundation_4").ConnectionString
                Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.CommandText = "Sophia_FND_SalesOrder_CREATE"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@contact", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(drpcontact.SelectedValue)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@deliveryAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtdelivery.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Charge", SqlDbType.Float).Value = lblCharge_unformated.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@GrossTotal", SqlDbType.Float).Value = total
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PaymentMode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = drpPayMode.SelectedItem.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@organisationId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SessionWrapper.OrganisationId
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SessionWrapper.LoggedInUserID
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@amtpaid", SqlDbType.Float).Value = 0
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@duration", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(lblduration.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SalesOrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                cmd.Connection = con
                Try
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    sale_id = cmd.Parameters("@SalesOrderId").Value


                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                    con.Dispose()
                End Try
end if
```